# Cartoon episode where aliens think squirrels control the Earth

Tags: story-identification, animation

I am trying to remember a cartoon episode where aliens think squirrels control the Earth. I think it was an episode in a cartoon but it could've been part of a movie. I have tried looking it up online but can't seem to come up with anything.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year (or range of years) did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, did you watch this on TV or online?

Comment: Obligatory mention that [Season 3 Episode 8 of *Rick and Morty*](https://www.reddit.com/r/rickandmorty/comments/70sjvy/comment/dn5mwzr/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) has the revelation that squirrels *do* control the world.

Comment: I had the same thought that FuzzyBoots did -- take a look and see if this seems familiar:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpZZQ2ov4lc&t=45s

Answer (score 5):

A possibility would be the cartoon tv-series *[Monsters vs Aliens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsters_vs._Aliens_(TV_series))*, first shown in 2013, and based on the 2009 film of the same name. In episode 5a, *It came... on a field trip*, a young alien named Sqweep comes to Earth to do a school project on Earth Studies, and concludes that squirrels are the Earth's dominant life form. In case this jogs the OP's memory, this is how Sqweep looks:

[image: Picture of Sqweep, a small pink alien]